# How I can do disable onTouch in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I have a fragment `class FlipFragment : Fragment()`
which include CircleShape. When I press to the CircleShape , I call method which change resource of it with some animation. I need to do that , when animation is working - onTouch is disable. How I can do it?

```
class FlipFragment : Fragment() {
  private var layout = R.layout.view_flip
  private lateinit var CircleShape: ImageView


  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
      savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var view: View = inflater!!.inflate(layout, container, false)
    CircleShape = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.fShapeView)
    Log.i("TAG", CircleShape.isClickable.toString())
    CircleShape.setOnClickLiastener { mechanics() }

    return view
  }
   private fun mechanics() {
    var mechanics = Mechanics(context, this.CircleShape, R.drawable.front_circle,
        R.drawable.back_circle,
        fCircleShapeView)
    mechanics.animation()   ///when this method is working - onTouch should be disable
    mechanics.random()

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a listener as AnimationListener.
*Example:*

```
Mechanics.addAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        yourView.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        yourView.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
})
```